# Variance properties of transformed p-values using the standard normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, p-value, normalization

I am searching for a reference or proof for the following situation:

Let t_df denote a t-test statistic for given degree of freedom df. The null hypothesis being tested is H_0: $\delta$ <= 0. Typically, this hypothesis is tested on the edge of the null hypothesis, hence it is tested for $\delta = 0 $. Now, let $\Psi$(t_df)_df represent the cumulative density function for the t-distribution with df degrees of freedom. This will transform the test statistic to its corresponding p-values. This p-value will be a uniform distribution on 0 to 1 for $\delta=0$. Now, if $\Phi^{-1}$ denotes the inverse quantile function of a standard normal distribution, then the distribution of $\Phi^{-1}$(p) follows the normal distribution N(0,1). So far I have no problem.

However, what happens for scenarios where $\delta<0$? What distributions will the p-values take on? They do not follow a uniform distribution anymore. What distribution will $\Phi^{-1}$(p) then have? Using simulations I can empirically determine that the distribution follows N($\mu<0$, $\sigma<1$). I am particularly interested in the variance part, so I would at least like to prove that $\sigma<1$ in such situations. Could somebody point me to a way to prove this, a paper where this was shown or a book this might have been explained?

Comment: The calculations are straightforward, so you don't necessarily need to find it in the literature; but the results depend on $\delta.$  Neither the t-statistic nor the associated p-value will follow a Normal distribution, though.

Comment: @RGG The distribution function of $p$ under the null should always lie $\leq$ (equal to or below / to the right of) the standard uniform, even with discrete test statistics or composite nulls (that is, $p$ should be stochastically at least as large as a uniform). That's the case here. The distribution of the test statistic here should be [*non-central t*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) with non-centrality parameter a function of the specific mean-parameter $\theta$, $\sigma$ and $\sqrt{n}$ (specifically $\theta\sqrt{n}/\sigma$ if I have it right).

Comment: I would even say that any p-value distribution for $\delta<0$ is stochastically larger than Univ[0,1]. However, I do not know how that property affects the quantiles after transformation to a normal distribution and how it affects the variance of that distribution. That is what I am mainly. So that I can say:
Var($\Phi^{-1}(\Psi(t__{df}))$) <1
for $\delta<0$. 
I thought of using the relationship between the t-distribution and the normal distribution: 
$T_{df} = \delta + \sigma * N(0,1)/ \sqrt{\chi^2_{df}/df}$. However that route disregards the transformation to the p-values first. Advice??